# click the Android studio > Android SDK，then the whole app will look like blocking then i can't click any where

Tags: android

every time.
when I use AS,
click

Android studio>preferences>Appearance & Behave>System Settings>Android SDK

when i click the `Android SDK` or`updates`.

the whole app is blocked,i can't click any where.

so i have to force quit the AS & relaunch it.

or wait for nearly 5min..this is total unbearable.

NEED HELP,any one have ideas about this?

Answer (score 0):

The above problem that you mentioned occurs because,**Android Studio** requires 4GB RAM to RUN Smoothly which may not be in your Computer.
So,the other option for Android Development is Download **Eclipse** from this Link-->https://eclipse.org/downloads/ and then perform.

Comment: no,i don't think the problem is the RAM, my computer have 8GB RAM.